# TableView to detailTableView - one step behind

Tags: iphone, tableview, master-detail

When I connect the my tableView to a detailtableView I get the the "error" that the detailtableView is one step behind. For example when clicking the 2nd cell in the mastertableView it show the 1st cell detailInformation. Hope you understand my problem.

See my .m.

```
#import "GuideTableViewController.h"
#import "GuideDetailTableViewController.h"

@interface GuideTableViewController (){
    NSArray *guide;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation GuideTableViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


//JSONmetod
- (void) loadJSON{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //code
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropbox.com/u/100670549/test.json"]];

        NSError *error;

        if (data)
        {

            guide = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

            for (NSDictionary *dictionary in guide){
                NSLog([dictionary description]);
            }


        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"Could not load data");
        }




            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // code
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });


    });


    }




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Anropa json

    [self loadJSON];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//TableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return guide.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


    NSDictionary *dict = [guide objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}


//Till detailView

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showStay"]){
        GuideDetailTableViewController *tvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *index = sender;
        NSDictionary *dict = [guide objectAtIndex:index.row];

        tvc.stay = dict;
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showStay" sender:indexPath];


}




@end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you used `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Delegate method, common autocomplete mistake.

Comment: detailTableView is not one step behind your delegate method is..
hahahahahhahah hahahha h ah ..

Comment: THANKS Jonathan...did my day!...yes autocomplete can be hard for a beginner.

Comment: Spent three hours cursing my project for not calling a segue from a UITableViewCell. And it comes down to two letters